# I want to pass dynamic Data From Database to Doughnut Chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have Some Data that I want to pass dynamically to a Doughnut Chart of Chart.js Library,But I tried to make it but it does not work.

```
  <script>
  var OrganizationsPriceRanges= 
     @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.OrganizationsPriceRanges));
   var PriceRangesList=  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.PriceRangesList));


       var doughnutData = [
            {
                value: OrganizationsPriceRanges,
                color:["#F7464A","#FDB45C","#4D5360"],
                highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                label: PriceRangesList
            },



        ];


            var ctx = 
           document.getElementById("PriceRanges").getContext("2d");
            window.myDoughnut = new 
       Chart(ctx).Doughnut(doughnutData, {responsive : true});
         </script>
```

Comment: If you want dynamic data then you need AJAX to get the data, the database to return a JSON object so  the web page can use the returned information.

Comment: data is already in json format my problem is how to pass it to the chart